# Nagios simple dashboard

Tags: nagios

I am looking for a dead simple dashboard for Nagios so our IT team can view the status of our services.
In an old version of what's up gold, it was a nice dashboard with different rectangular shape being red, yellow or green depending on the status of the service and could be display easily on a screen.

Is there some copycat dashboard for nagios ? any better recommendation ?
I want something you can see from your desk 15meters away: red or green, no need for details.

Comment: Have you tried the various screens available in Nagios? What you're asking for is already there. Just give them a link to the screen that best suits the situation.

Comment: I think what you looking for is the nagios core dashboard. Without graphical plugin.

like these >>> http://server-world.info/en/CentOS_5/nagios/img/10.jpg

It's what you have when you only install nagios. Pretty pure, easy to read, I love it. (not too found in the centreon plugin and co.


More screen exemple here >>> http://server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_5&p=nagios

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find my own CoffeeSaint very usefull.

Especially on large screens in your serverroom.

Unfortunately I cannot paste screendumps here as I'm a new user. But on the CoffeeSaint website there are plenty of them: http://www.vanheusden.com/java/CoffeeSaint/

Comment: +1 So you can post screenshots anytime soon! From "Guda", eh? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Icinga](https://www.icinga.org/) and [Icinga-web](https://www.icinga.org/screenshots/new-web/). It's 100% compatible with your nagios-config and looks a lot nicer if you ask me.

[image: Icinga-web]

Answer (score 1):

I think [Centreon](http://www.centreon.com/) could meet your requirements... even though it is really more than a simple dashboard. It offers you tools to configure your supervision server, too...

Answer (score 1):

Can be seen from 15 meters away?
Check out [Naglite3](https://github.com/saz/Naglite3), which is a modification of [Naglite2](http://laur.ie/blog/2010/03/naglite2-finally-released/).

They read the information from the Nagios / Icinga "status.dat" and show it in a "dashboard-like" way:

[image]

**Update, March 2013**

I've replace the above mentioned dashboard(s) with [Nagdash](https://github.com/lozzd/Nagdash) to monitor multiple Nagios / Icinga instances from one instance.
This is how it looks on a 22 inch monitor (while going through a DDoS):

[image: nagdash]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you RealOpInsight (http://RealOpInsight.com). It's a high level GUI Dashboard providing a view on business processes healthy (see the screenshot below or the website for more screenshots)! It also enables an embedded web browser to allow you to keep an eye on your default Nagios UI.
In bonus, it supports other monitoring systems such Zabbix, Icinga, Shinken and even Zenoss.

[image: RealOpInsight Screenshot]